# Html2canvas only capture screensize and not the entire div container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html2canvas

I am trying to capture whole "div container" in one image using html2canvas. For some reason im only getting the part which shows on my screen. But I have a horizontal scroll on the div so I would like to capture whats not on my screen aswell but the content inside the div.

Is that possible? Right now my div is 5000px width, can i capture it all in one image somehow?

Here is my javascript code for html2canvas:

```
$(function() { 
 $("#btnSave").click(function() {
 });
    html2canvas($("#container_wrapper_anatomy"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            theCanvas = canvas;

            var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
            window.open(dataUrl, "toDataURL() image", "width=100%, height=100%");

            canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
                saveAs(blob, "container_wrapper_anatomy.jpg"); 
              });
          }
      });
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance.